# Relation between Nash equilibrium , subgame perfect equilibrium, backward induction, perfect Bayesian equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

My claims are

1- Backward induction solution is Nash equilibrium solution.

2- Not all Nash equilibria are sequentially rational

3- All Backward induction solutions are sequentially rational

4- SPNE solutions are Nash equilibria

5- SPNE solutions are sequentially rational if game has at least one 
proper sub game. If only has improper sub game then it may not be sequentially rational.

6- PBE solutions are Nash equilibrium and SPNE

7- PBE solutions are sequentially rational no matter what.

8- WPBE solutions are Nash equilibria. And sequentially rational no matter what.

Are these true? What do you think? Anything want to add?

Comment: As @HerrK. points out in his answer whether these statements are true or false depend on the exact definitions you are using. Please include them in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Backward induction solution is Nash equilibrium solution. **TRUE**

2- Not all Nash equilibria are sequentially rational. **TRUE**; *NE allows for sequentially irrational behavior off equilibrium path.*

3- All Backward induction solutions are sequentially rational. **TRUE**

4- SPNE solutions are Nash equilibria. **TRUE**

5- SPNE solutions are sequentially rational if game has at least one proper sub game. **FALSE** *(Counterexample below: the game has one proper subgame; $(XC,L)$ is an SPNE but involves a sequentially irrational strategy $L$ by player 2).* If only has improper sub game then it may not be sequentially rational. **TRUE** *(Treat the subgame after $X$ as a game of its own.)*

[image]

6- PBE solutions are Nash equilibrium and SPNE. **UNCERTAIN / TRUE (in most cases)**; *it actually depends on how exactly you define PBE (there are many definitions). See [Watson (2017)](http://econweb.ucsd.edu/~jwatson/PAPERS/WatsonPBE.pdf) for more details.*

7- PBE solutions are sequentially rational no matter what. **TRUE**

8- WPBE solutions are Nash equilibria. And sequentially rational no matter what. **TRUE**

Comment: 7,8 also seems to depend on the definition. The definition for PBE I knew stated that the strategies were sequentially rational and the beliefs consistent.

Comment: @denesp: Thanks. I misread 5, and have fixed my answer. I agree with you on 7 and 8 after thinking about it a bit harder. Those statements are true by definition. I must have had the wrong thing for breakfast today `:(`